# Sudo keeps asking for password, despite that NOPASSWD already set

Tags: macos, unix, sudo

The following sudoers configuration used to work well in MacOS 10.8.5, several days ago I upgraded to Mavericks, NOPASSWD flag does not seem to work anymore:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
howard  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Mavericks' sudo still asks for entering password.

Is there any resolution/workaround?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The group entry `%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL` seems to override the user specific entry. 
I found moving the user specific entry so that is appears after the group entry fixes this. Maybe sudo parses the entire file and it uses the last matching entry?

Changing your sudoers file to something similar to below should work.

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
howard  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I assume you wanted to write *before* instead of *after*?

Comment: No, that's how OP has it now. I found that the user entry (with NOPASSWD) really needs be on a line after the group entry (which doesn't have NOPASSWD) or sudo will prompt for the password.

Comment: Ah right, misread your post. Maybe you can update your answer to show a complete *good* sample

Comment: You're right. I've cleaned up the original answer and added an an example.

Comment: It helps, thanks a lot, but I am still wondering why such issue does not appear on my Linux instance, perhaps MacOS is using a different sudo version.